# Disable a button based on a specific value selected in mat-select

Tags: angular

I use angular/material

```js
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

The html has a selection element

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select book</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="newBookId">
      <mat-option [value]="null">no book</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="book cat of books" [value]="book.id">
        {{book.bookName}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>    

<mat-dialog-actions>  
    <button
       mat-raised-button color="primary"
       [disabled]= ???
    >
      Save
    </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

How do I make the "Save" button blocked if "no book" is selected in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `[disabled]= "selectedBook==undefined"` . Here is my sample code below=>

**HTML:**

```
  <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select name="bookVaraible" [(value)]="selectedBook" placeholder="Book" (selectionChange)="myChange($event.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let book of books" [value]="book">
              {{book.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        Selected = {{selectedBook?.name}}
    
        <br>
        <button
           mat-raised-button color="primary"
           [disabled]= "selectedBook==undefined"
        >
          Save
        </button>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
   books=[];
  selectedBook: any=undefined;
  constructor() {
    for(let i=1;i<4;i++){
      let temp=new Books();
      temp.id=i;
      temp.name="BKK-"+i;
      this.books.push(temp);
    }
    //this.selectedBook=this.books[0];
  }
  myChange($event){
    console.log($event);
  }
}
export class Books{
  id:number;
  name:string;
}
```

**Note:** Please check the link [Stackblitz Demo Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-5h5dmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

check your "newBookId" is undefined or not and disable according to that

```
 <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Select book</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="newBookId">
          <mat-option [value]="null">no book</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="book cat of books" [value]="book.id">
            {{book.bookName}}
          </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>    
    
    <mat-dialog-actions>  
        <button
           mat-raised-button color="primary"
           [disabled]="newBookId == undefined"
        >
          Save
        </button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[disabled]="newBookId === 'no book'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a template reference variable with the `mat-select` -

```html
<mat-select [(value)]="newBookId" #select>
```

and then check if its value is `null` (which is the value you have set for "no book" option) -

```html
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="select.value==null"> Save </button>
```